# Horizontal two-line css menu issue

Tags: css, html-lists

I am trying to create a horizontal menu with CSS with ul, li elements. The goal is to accomplish the following: whenever the menu option is too long, the text goes to second line, vertically and horizontally aligned.

I managed to make that work, however when the option is two-lined, it automatically get the max-width parameter as its width, and doesn't set to option's actual width. However, when the option is one line -- it does set to its actual width. Is max-width a wrong parameter for what I am trying to achieve? I *do* want the li element to be the same width as its contents.

HTML:

```
<ul class="trials">
   <li><span><a href="#">kitchen furniture</a></span></li>
   <li><span><a href="#">wardrobes & cabinets</a></span></li>
   <li><span><a href="#">hallway furniture</a></span></li>
   <li><span><a href="#">materials</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.trials {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     float: right;
}
.trials li {
     display: inline-block;
     list-style: none;
     margin-left: 10px;
}
.trials li {
     max-width: 130px; 
     line-height: 40px;
     height: 40px;
     border: 1px blue solid;        
}
.trials li span {
     display: -moz-inline-box; /* FF2 or lower */
     display: inline-block; /* FF3, Opera, Safari */
     line-height: normal;
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: center;
}
.trials li span { 
     *display  : inline; /* haslayout for IE6/7 */
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/so_artistic/ecCM4/

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Want submenu item to wrap when text longer than width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074811/want-submenu-item-to-wrap-when-text-longer-than-width)

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the same issue.

Comment: Follow the same advice, and all work work out perfectly. You don't need a SPAN and you should be styling the A-tag, not the list itself.

Comment: I am aware of that, I did style <span>, not the inline element like the person in the other question you linked to. I added the <a> tag and intended to clean my code later, my mistake to leave it in the fiddle. Removing it doesn't fix my issue -- I want the inline element width to adjust to both one-line and two-line text automatically, without having to break the line manually.

Answer (score 0):

IDihtjara,

There are two options here.

My first solution was to add `width: 130px` and remove `max-width: 130px`. This ensures that the text wraps around for two-line `li` items, but also ensures that they are all the same size. Unfortunately, you can't force text to wrap to two lines by setting a `max-width` but also expect that text to size the box. [- jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WW3P4/1/)

You could also simply add a `<br/>` to the text to manually cause a line break. This would enable your buttons to match the size of the text within them. [- jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tPyf/1/)

Really, there are more options that involve javascript, which might detect if each element is larger than `130px`, then resize it with javascript while keeping the width set to the width of the words. Something like this is possible, but not necessarily practial.

I've also removed every `span` from your code. Both `span` and `a` are `inline` elements initially, which makes using the `span` grouping element redundant for each individual `li`. There's no reason to have a `span` in addition to the `a` tag unless there is more markup/more complicated things going on with your code.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping to avoid using <br/> and still get the boxes to adjust to the two-line text width.